# Windows phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to develop app for windows phone but I got a big problem, my laptop can't run the emulator, after checking the requirements I know that my vga driver doesn't support it. My question is, are there any alternative for windows phone emulator instead of the officially one from Microsoft? Or any other way to tweak it to be run on my laptop? Thanks

Comment: Strange post. Many other components should fail the test before the screen itself for qualification to Windows 8 + Hyper-V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding there isn't any other windows phone emulators. If you can get a hold of a windows phone 7 it would be possible to test on that. You can try to contact a Microsoft windows phone evangelist in your area, the one in my area helped me get a phone to test on.

I am not sure about tweakinging your laptop to get the emulator to work. Is your vga driver up to date? If not maybe try to update it. I know it takes quite a bit of computer power to run the emulator smoothly.

If you wanted you can try to register for a virtual lab, here you remote into a windows machine and are able to build and test on the remote machine, but it is time limted and is usually for a class to learn about it. https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/EventDetail.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032485600&amp%3bculture=en-US

Comment: thanks you for your info, but btw what is Microsoft windows phone evangelist?

Comment: I am not sure where you live, so not 100% sure if there would be a Microsoft Phone evangelist, but they go around and help developers out who are programming apps for Windows Phone. But you can check out this app and they list windows phone "champs" in your area "champs" are the evangilists. http://findmychamp.codeplex.com/

Comment: The creator of the findmychamp app is Jerry Nixon, he is a Windows phone Evangelist. If you are having trouble finding one in your area, maybe contact him to see who your local champ is. His blog is at http://blog.jerrynixon.com/